# Generating an int within a certain range based on two variables

Tags: php, math

I'm making an anonymous commenting system for my blog. I need the users to have a randomly picked username from an array I have made, it has 600 usernames. I can't just make it random because then people wouldn't know if it was the same person posting a reply, so I have given each post a randomly generated key between 1-9999, using the key and the users ID I want to do some sort of calculation so that number will stay consistent through that particular post. The result has to be within 1-600.

something like:

```
user_id x foo(1-9999) = bar(1-600)
```

Thanks.

Comment: That would be a random int, I need one that's constant based on the ID and the randomly generated postkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). To quote Wikipedia:

> A hash function is any algorithm or subroutine that maps large data sets of variable length, called keys, to smaller data sets of a fixed length.

So you can use a standard hash function, plus modular arithmetic to further map the output of that hash function to your username range, like so:

```
function anonymise($username, $post_key) {
    $hash = hash("adler32", "$username/$post_key");
    $hash_decimal = base_convert($hash, 16, 10);
    $anonymised_id = $hash_decimal % 600;

    return $usernames[$anonymised_id];
}
```

Comment: While this would be great if I wanted them to be a constant all the time, but I need them to change based on the postkey.

Comment: So concatenate the post key to the username (editing to reflect)

Answer (score 0):

So, what you really want is a unique identifier for every poster?

Why not use http://php.net/ip2long modded 600?

of course, you'll have to do some collision detection with that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using md5 on the concatinated id and post key. it gives you a consistent 32 byte hash of that. And it is actually a hexadecimal string, so you can actually covet it to a number easily by doing a hex to int conversion.

Edit: Based on your feedback. you can take the generated int and modulas it by 600.

Comment: that would be cool, but I need the result to always be within 1-600.

Comment: Just mod 600. Only problem is that with a bucket size so small, the chances of getting a duplication is higher. i have updated my answer.